# JavaScript: Cannot read properties of undefined reading "size", even though "size" is already defined

Tags: javascript

This returns the undefined error:

```
function spawnCreature() {
    var creature = {
        size: 10,
        x: (Math.random() * (land.width - (creature.size / 2)) + (creature.size / 2)),
        y: (Math.random() * (land.height - (creature.size / 2)) + (creature.size / 2)),
        dirX: 0,
        dirY: 0,
    }
    creatureArray.push(creature);
}
```

Despite that, I tried to fix it with this:

```
function spawnCreature() {
    var creatureSize = 10;
    var creature = {
        size: creatureSize,
        x: (Math.random() * (land.width - (creatureSize / 2)) + (creatureSize / 2)),
        y: (Math.random() * (land.height - (creatureSize / 2)) + (creatureSize / 2)),
        dirX: 0,
        dirY: 0,
    }
    creatureArray.push(creature);
}
```

But all that happened was the creature wasn't anywhere in the land.

Comment: The error message means it's `creature` that isn't defined, not `size`. Check `creature`.

Comment: the first error is because you are trying to use a property of an object while trying to instantiate that same object. Your second problem will fix that, but we will need a lot more information to help debug what you are really asking

Comment: You are trying to reference `creature` prior to the completion of its assignment.

Comment: in my opinion the creature must be a ghost, and it is well known that they have no real size

Comment: Size might be a reserved word, try using something else and observe.

Comment: You own fix should work. What problem else? You should ask another question if this problem is fixed and you are facing a new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing properties from `creature` even when it is not defined completely. All of this is in the same statement and `creature` has no meaning until after the first statement is completely executed.

```js
  var creature = {
        size: 10,
        x: (Math.random() + (creature.size / 2)),
        y: (Math.random()  + (creature.size / 2)),
        dirX: 0,
        dirY: 0,
    }
    
    console.log(creature);
```